# Give access to specific user to files in private s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a `s3` bucket that is private and I want specific user to have access to some objects in this bucket. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: You can achieve this by generating pre-signed URLs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: i gave above bucket policy but not working

Comment: Thanks Blair,But  there are so many objects in bucket

Comment: do you an AWS access key-pair that you authenticate with when using the AWS CLI?

Comment: How do you define "specific user"? Is this somebody in your company that has IAM User credentials? Or is this a user of your application? If the latter, do you authenticate the user first? Please Edit your question to add more details rather than answering via a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For individuals objects, you should use **Pre-signed URL**.
It allows the user who access the URL to issue a request as the person who pre-signed the URL (inheriting the permissions of the IAM user that generated the URL). It can be generated with SDK or CLI. It is valid for 3600s by default, but you can change this duration.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html

For multiple objetcs (if you want a path with wildcard), you can use **Signed cookies**. It need you to first implements a `CloudFront` distribution in front of you `s3` bucket.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

CloudFront also allow to provide **Signed URLs**, which are different from S3 Presigned-URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html